# error : file.java must be in the directory c:\jcute\tests

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have installed Jcute and I'm trying to run a simple Java Code to see how it works.

But when I try to compile I get the below error message :

> error message : test.java must be in the directory c:\jcute\src\

Image attached -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6MtV.png)

root directory for Jcute -> `c:\Jcute`

Can you please tell me what have I done wrong?

Comment: Try moving the class test.java inside the /src folder

Comment: it is in the /src folder

Comment: The error in your title and the content of the question differs. I am guessing either of them tried should be the solution to your problem.

Comment: its basically an error with any file im trying to compile.( its just an example i have mentioned in the title with a file named "file.java")

Comment: Okay. Please share the complete error that you get.  And the way you're trying to execute the tests.

Comment: okay. The error message is : "test.java must be in the directory c:\jcute\tests ". Tests is a folder in src and the file to be compiled is placed in Tests folder. To compile my file i run the jcute.bat file and upload the path of the src directory and the path of the file to be compiled. After this when I try to compile i get the error message.

Comment: **I run the jcutegui.bat file

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss the package statement `package tests;` in your `src\tests\test1.java` file.

Find below working examples.

**src\tests\Test.java**

```
package tests;
class Test {
    public static int foo() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

**src\Test.java**

```
class Test {
    public static int bar() {
        return 23;
    }
}
```

Above source at least was successfully loaded with the binary version from [jCUTE homepage](http://osl.cs.illinois.edu/software/jcute/jcute-bin.zip).

Comment: no, the package statement was included in the test file. The problem seems to be with the system as mine is a 64 bit machine and jcute download is available for 32 bit machine.